# Expand and Collapse events in SlickGrid

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

How can I register to `onCollapse` and `onExpand` events on SlickGrid with DataView?

I need to track the status of the groups -- which are expanded and which are collapsed.

Answer (score 3):

**In short:** you can't do that. There are no such events in the [`SlickGrid`](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Grid-Events) object and neither in [`DataView`](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView).

---

**In long:**

1. **First method:**
   The grid has an `onClick` method, which you could subscribe to. However subscribing this event only works for *cell* or *row* clicks, even works on the group row but not when you click expand or collapse. This *event* doesn't get propagated to the <kbd>-</kbd> or the <kbd>+</kbd> `span` elements that you can click on the group rows.
2. **Second method**
   The DataView has an on `onRowsChanged` event, which you could subscribe to as well. For example you can try doing it from your JS debugger console as: `dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function(e, args) {console.log(args.rows);});`
   Using this event could seem that we are one step closer, since the expand/collapse button click raises it. However the `args` parameter that we are receiving in our *anonymous function* contains only information about the *rows* needed to be updated on the grids canvas.
3. **Last chance (a.k.a. don't try these at home or the *hackish methods*)**
   I have tried all the possible ways to get around this, with no success. I will list these below just as reference (as of SlickGrid v2.2).

   - `$('.slick-group').click(function(){console.log()});`
   - `$('.slick-group-toggle').click(function(){console.log()});`

The attempts listed above only works for the first expand or collapse, since after the action, they are getting detached and attached to the DOM and the grid canvas if they fit (based on the `DataView.onRowsChanged` events `args` parameter which I have mentioned in point **2.** above).

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. !!

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still looking for a solution, here is how I implemented it.
I had to hide some content in the group row when expanded, so I needed to have a collapsed/expanded class directly on the group row.
For this, I used `dataView.getItemMetadata` :

```
var getRowMetadata = function(old_metadata_provider) {
    return function (row) {
        var item = this.getItem(row),
            ret = old_metadata_provider(row);

        //Handle group rows
        if (item.__group) {
            //adding a class
            ret.cssClasses += ' ' + (item.collapsed === 1 ? 'collapsed' : 'expanded');
            //or trigger a custom event....
        }
        //"Normal rows"
        else if (item) {
            ret = ret || {};
            ...
        }
        return ret;
    };
};


....

dataview = new Slick.Data.DataView({
    groupItemMetadataProvider: groupItemMetadataProvider,
    inlineFilters: true
});
dataview.getItemMetadata = getRowMetadata(dataview.getItemMetadata);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old but just thought I would share my solution. It is possible to access the click event for expanding or collapsing groups!

My solution was quite straight forward. You need to override `handleGridClickEvent` set within `GroupItemMetadataProvider`.

So to do this.. right after you register the `groupItemMetadataProvider` plugin, you call `destroy()` to unsubscribe the default `handleGridClickEvent` like so..

```
this.grid.registerPlugin(groupItemMetadataProvider);

// unsubscribes the default click event handler for grouped rows so we can provide our own which will save the state of the expanders
groupItemMetadataProvider.destroy();
```

You can then simply copy the function from within `GroupItemMetadataProvider` and add in any extra functionality you wish..

```
// On expander click event. This is attached to the grid.onClick but checks for the expander css class
// The function has been taken from slick.groupitemmetadataprovider.js (handleGridClick) and modified to save the expander states
// to local storage.
function onExpanderClick(e, args) {
    ... 
}
```

In your function.. to ensure the expander element has been clicked you can look at the css class of the event

```
$(e.target).hasClass('slick-group-toggle')
```

you can see the state of the expander using `item.collapsed` and add whatever functionality you want depending on the state of the expanders.

Finally subscribe your new function as one of the grids onClick events like so..

```
grid.onClick.subscribe(onExpanderClick);
```

Comment: just so you know, new Group Expand/Collapse events were added recently in the 6pac repo, see this [PR](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/pull/464)